# How to have UTF-8 encoding in struct pack_into function while packing data

Tags: python-3.x

I have a string say

```
res='1532444791.966564        0088    000    8    78 78 78 78 78 77 77 78'
```

I wanted to pack this in byte array

```
array = struct.pack("dlqqq",float(res[0:24]),int(res[25:32]),int(res[39:44]),int(res[45:67].replace(" ","")),int(res[40:44]))
```

after this I send the array to server.

```
server.sendall(arr)
```

but I get an error saying the encoding error and the server expects UTF-8 encoding.

Is there a better way to do this or is there a way to send in the encdoing of the bytes (as it was not there in documentation of the pack)

Note I am using python 3,6

Comment: UTF-8 is for text. You are sending binary data. Review the requirements carefully.

Comment: If the server expects UTF-8 encoding, you should probably send the string in bytes, encoded as UTF-8: `mystring.encode()` (since the default encoding is UTF-8 since Python 3.2).

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams then how do I convert the bytearray to string . I am not able to get it. array.decode gives the following error
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xdc in position 1: invalid continuation byte

Comment: Of course you can't; you're trying to satisfy conflicting requirements. Which is why you need to **review them carefully**.

Comment: yeah your are right I should have used struct.unpack("<dlqqq", array). Thank you @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams